# Best technology for a Tetris-like Windows Phone 7 game

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

What's the best technology for a Tetris-like game for Windows Phone 7? Silverlight or XNA? The best is in terms of easier to learn and faster to implement.

Comment: You need to define what 'better' is. Do you mean speed, control, ease of learning, ease of coding etc etc... Otherwise this question will be closed as 'not a real question'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/windowsphone7series/thread/2dcd11bb-7093-4057-b0e9-24451b32a5b5

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/which_product_for_windows_phone

Those are some links you may find useful, I have never developed in silverlight. But the first topic has some questions about it and the second is an article on app hub on which is right for wp7.

Answer (score 1):

this question is difficult because what is easy to learn? maybe for you XNA can be better, maybe not.

do you know this tutorial?
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started